# Access_denied resource owner password credentials flow in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I followed this article below, but I got the error below from Test the user flow section:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-ms-gateway-requestid: fd437d7a-fd0e-42bf-adcf-0969f5dcf74d
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Set-Cookie: x-ms-cpim-trans=; domain=mytenant.b2clogin.com; expires=Tue, 29-Jan-2019 13:35:09 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 13:35:08 GMT
Content-Length: 217

{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"AADB2C90225: The username or password provided in the request are invalid.\r\nCorrelation ID: 9b3c19e2-6084-4bcd-b7d3-aab8d2c34dd9\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-30 13:35:09Z\r\n"}
```

Request sent:

```
POST https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROPC_Auth HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: mytenant.b2clogin.com

username=myemail&password=password&grant_type=password&scope=openid myappId offline_access&client_id=myappId&response_type=token+id_token
```

I am a global admin, but I am able to create User flow, Register application etc.

I am using Fiddler to send the request, so it is not related to WebApp/WebAPI.

The user name (e.g. myname@myfirm.com) and password are correct, which is used to login azure portal to setup the sample.

Any idea?

**Update**

Please note the user that I use is in User role in my firm's active directory, but the user is a global admin in the active directory associated with the newly created AD B2C tenant following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

Comment: Please see update on OP.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom). You will get this error message because the instruction in step 4 is wrong.

In your TrustFrameworkExtensions file. you should have something like this in you Local Account SignIn ClaimsProvider -> TechnicalProfiles

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2">
    <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureADB2C-Tenant-Name}.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AzureADB2C-Tenant-Name}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="logonIdentifier" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Password}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{Proxy-Identity-Experience-Framework-ClientId}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="{Identity-Experience-Framework-ClientId}" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**Note the resource_id should be IdentityExperienceFramework application (client) Id, not ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** as described in Microsoft's documentation.  I had submitted a request to correct this in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

The resource owner password credentials flow, which is described by [the Configure the resource owner password credentials flow in Azure AD B2C article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc), is not designed to authenticate credentials for an administrator user.

It is designed to authenticate credentials for an end user who has either (a) been [created as a local account using the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser) or (b) registered themselves using a sign-up flow.

Comment: Do you mean all adminstrator users cannot use ROPC, regardless of conditions a and b you mentioned? Why do we have such a rule in B2C? Can you provide link on this if possible? Is there a workaround for admin users or this case?

Comment: All our employees are already in azure AD. Is it correct that based on what you said, all employees have to be migrated to a new Azure AD for B2C, and they must be local account, not admin user.

Comment: The user account used for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496543/404-not-found-error-via-resource-owner-password-credentials-flow-in-azure-ad-b2c is also global admin account, but the user is able to make the same request. So is the issue still related to global admin issue, or something else?